# Are paint buckets removed permanently after use?

Tags: the-talos-principle

By permanently, I mean:

> When the player choses to go through the gates and gets reset, are the paint buckets that they used in a previous run also reset? Because I haven't been able to find any of the ones I used in previous runs, but I have found several that I had not used before.

Comment: I didn't check, but for me it is quite obvious that the writings should stay permanently. Your friends can see them, so you kind of write it for friends to see, and you wouldn't want repeat all this job after reset. So the buckets should be removed permanently as well.

Comment: It's kind of a plot hole then, though, because you can see others have left messages multiple times on the same level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can find more on later cycles.

You only receive at most one paint bucket per run in any area that has them. However, each area has multiple locations in which a paint bucket can spawn. It's also not guaranteed that any particular area will actually spawn a paint bucket on your particular run. Using a paint bucket will cause it to disappear from that area, but completing the first ending (the one that resets you back to the beginning of the game) will cause new paint buckets to spawn following the same rules, though not necessarily in the same locations.

[These images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9jWt.jpg) show 101 locations where paint buckets are known to spawn, which is supposedly all of them.